# Data binding, the async pipe, and child views

Tags: angular, async-pipe

I am pulling data from a database and then displaying that data in a component and a child component. In that child component, there is a popup where a user can edit data. When that data is edited, the changes are not reflected in the displayed data. I believe that this is because I use the async pipe in passing this data to the child elements.

I could avoid the async pipe, but that would lead to errors as I use ngIf statements that depend on this data.

Coming from AngularJS, this would be easy as I would just use the parent workspace in the child directive. What am I missing here?

Parent Component - userInfo is data being addressed

```
<!-- CONTENT -->
<div class="content">

    <ng-container *ngIf="(userInfo | async)?.data() as info">

        <mat-tab-group dynamicHeight="true"
                       style="width:60%; margin:0px 20%;">

            <mat-tab label="Bio">
                <profile-about [userData]='userData' [userInfo]="info"></profile-about>
            </mat-tab>

            <mat-tab label="Companies">
                <profile-companies [userData]='userData' [userInfo]="info"></profile-companies>
            </mat-tab>

        </mat-tab-group>

    </ng-container>

</div>
<!-- / CONTENT -->
```

Section of child component that displays the data

```
        <div class="content">

            <div class="info-line"
                 *ngIf="userInfo.occupation!==undefined">
                <div class="title">Occupation</div>
                <div class="info">{{userInfo.occupation}}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="info-line"
                 *ngIf="userInfo.skills!==undefined">
                <div class="title">Skills</div>
                <div class="info">{{userInfo.skills}}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="info-line"
                 *ngIf="userInfo.jobs!==undefined && userInfo.jobs.length>0">
                <div class="title">Jobs</div>
                <table class="info jobs">
                    <tr class="job" *ngFor="let job of userInfo.jobs">
                        <td class="company">{{job.title}}</td>
                        <td class="date">{{job.startdate}}-{{job.enddate}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>

        </div>
```

When the dialog is opened and edited in this child view, I try to set the data. It should update automatically as it is binded.

```
openDialog(type) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open( EditBioDialog, {
        panelClass: 'edit-bio-dialog',
        data: { userData: this.userData, userInfo: this.userInfo, type:type }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.userInfo = result;
      this.FirebaseService.updateDocDataUsingId( 'users', this.userData.uid, result )
    });

}
```

Comment: `the changes are not reflected in the displayed data` means it's not getting updated in parent as well as child component?

Comment: This could have something to do with change detection of Angular. Try updating the data immutably meaning all reference type properties (no matter how deeply nested) in the object and the object itself should be at different address in memory. I usually use the spread operator (...). (`{...} for objects and [...] for arrays`).

Comment: The updates in the data are not reflected anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is no two way binding. Angular (2+) relies on "data going down, events going up" mechanism. There is however a [shorthand notation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding-) for this pattern which sort of reflects two way binding. That's the `[(var)]` notation. In short this means that there should be an `@Input` on the child named `var` and an `Output` named `varChange`:

This will change your code like this:

child component ts:

```
@Input()
userInfo: UserInfo;

@Output()
readonly userInfoChange = new EventEmitter<UserInfo>();


openDialog(type) {
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    this.userInfoChange.emit(result);
    this.FirebaseService.updateDocDataUsingId( 'users', this.userData.uid, result )
  });
}
```

parent component template:

```
<mat-tab label="Companies">
  <profile-companies [userData]="userData" [userInfo]="info" (userInfoChange)="onUserInfoChange($event)"></profile-companies>
</mat-tab>
```

parent component ts:

```
private readonly userInfoUpdate = new Subject<{ data(): UserInfo }>();

readonly userInfo = merge(
  // this.where.ever.you.get.source()
  this.userInfoUpdate
)

onUserInfoChange(userInfo: UserInfo): void {
  // probably not like this
  this.userInfoUpdate.next({ data: () => userInfo });
}
```

Not knowing your underlying data structure, but you should update your source observable to reflect the new data. Or if you don't want it to be saved yet, you can use a `merge` observable which will reflect the update